# Variables conflict between Makefile and C code

Tags: c, makefile

In my C Makefile I have the following lines:

```
ifeq ($(VERBOSE_PRINT), TRUE)
  CFLAGS += -D TRUE
else
  CFLAGS += -D FALSE
endif
```

As you can tell by it's name, this flag indicated whether I should print debug statements or not.

In other place at my C code, I'm defining TRUE and FALSE with

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
```

Then when I'm trying to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
types.h:6:0: error: "FALSE" redefined [-Werror]
#define FALSE 0
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

If I delete the definition of TRUE and FALSE from my C code, my program get's crazy.

What's going on and how can I solve this conflict?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: What is the idea of defining TRUE if you want to print and otherwise FALSE? Don't you want to define DBPRINT (or something) to two different values, which you can then check against in your code? How does the part which uses the TRUE/FALSE definition look like? Please make a [mcve] to show enough of your code (including makefile) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I agree with your idea but I have no much room for playing with it since it's a defined assignment.
in my C code I basically do:

#if TRUE
  dbprint()
#endif. 

but I suspect that the #if will always be true since TRUE is also defined in my C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the compiler command line, `-DXYZ` is equivalent to `-DXYZ=1` (POSIX [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html)).  This means that with `-DFALSE` on the command line, you've got both `#define FALSE 1` and `#define FALSE 0`, which is a non-benign redefinition. Benign redefinition of a macro is OK (meaning that the sequence of replacement tokens is the same in both the current and new definition — see C11 [§6.10.3 Macro replacement ¶1-2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3)).

You need to use a different variable in your code to decide whether to do printing:

```
#ifdef VERBOSE_PRINT
    printf("Debugging!\n");
#endif
```

You can then use `-DVERBOSE_PRINT` on the command line to enable printing and leave it out to disable it.  Alternatively, you can use:

```
#if VERBOSE_PRINT
    printf("Debugging!\n");
#endif
```

Then your makefile can contain:

```
ifeq ($(VERBOSE_PRINT), TRUE)
  CFLAGS += -DVERBOSE_PRINT=TRUE
else
  CFLAGS += -DVERBOSE_PRINT=FALSE
endif
```

This technique is less common.  It will work as if you have `#define VERBOSE_PRINT 0` if you don't specify a value on the compiler command line (C11 [§6.10.1 Conditional inclusion ¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4)).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the same name for two different incompatible things, so you'll need to change one of them.  Most likely you want to change your Makefile, since what you have makes no sense.  Something like:

```
ifeq ($(VERBOSE_PRINT), TRUE)
  CFLAGS += -DDEBUG=1
else
  CFLAGS += -DDEBUG=0
endif
```

Then in your C code you can have

```
#if DEBUG
    printf( ... debugging messages ... )
#endif
```